# DESO library NX building get's stuck + Import not found

Tags: npm, npx

I want to implement DESO into my app. The most convenient way is probably the DESO library from their developer hub.

I want to be as precise as possible here. So first I downloaded the deso-protocol npm package. In the readme of this library is stated that it is generated with nx. So I downloaded that too. No big issues. And I should: Run `nx build deso-protocol` to build the library.(in readme). Than I get an error that there is no workspace, when I want to create one with "npx create-nx-workspace deso-protocol --preset=core" , nx gets stuck in that process.

So I decided to do it without the building(I don't quite now if that is needed, am new to npm) and just do it with the classic js imports.
The "import Deso from 'deso-protocol';" from the docs isn't working. Because the module imports have to start with "/" or "./" or sth. similar etc.

So I tried `import Deso from './node_modules/deso-protocol/src/index.js';`. That's not working. Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default

using `import { Deso } from './node_modules/deso-protocol/src/index.js';` doesn't work either because then Deso isn't found. I don't quite now what to do now.

### Edit

I use plain JavaScript. deso-protocol uses plain JavaScript too, I hope. There isn't much code yet:

Index.js file:

```
import Deso from './node_modules/deso-protocol/src/index.js';
```

test.html file:

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

That's it. I use http.server from Python to host the local server.

Answer (score 1):

Just install deso-protocol library from https://www.npmjs.com/package/deso-protocol with `npm i deso-protocol`

In your app import it as usual

```
import Deso from "deso-protocol";
```

And initialize

```
const deso = new Deso();
```

Readme file is really confusing, I have no idea what

> Run nx build deso-protocol to build the library.

is supposed to mean, it works without that no problem.